# CruiseControl.Net restarts after project with msbuild task

Tags: msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

I'm trying to setup a fairly simple CruiseControl.NET build server and I'm seeing strange behavior with a project using MSBuild. Everytime the project's build is run and it executes msbuild (either through forcing or through a change in source control), the build completes successfully but CCNet also restarts. I notice this because the 'Next Build Time' of all the projects are moved ahead to the current time + initialSeconds.

This behavior appears whether I'm running CCNet as a serivce or through the command line executable. 
When running on the command line, the debug output doesn't give me anything useful - it just immediately jumps from the last line of the project's build to the 'startup' output.

Additional information:

- TFS is the source control server
- My build is only hitting the working directory
- My publish is just copying from the working directory to the artifact directory
- If I comment out the msbuild task, running the project build does not restart CruiseControl
- Not hitting or updating the Server or State directories of CruiseControl during build
- Nothing useful in Event Viewer when this happens and I'm running as a service. CCService doesn't report stopping/starting - it's like cruise control is internally restarting.

And here is the msbuild configuration:

`<tasks> 
  <msbuild>
    <executable>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe</executable>
    <workingDirectory>$[$CCNetWorkingDirectory]\$(PathToSolution)</workingDirectory>
    <projectFile>$(SolutionFile)</projectFile>
    <buildArgs>/p:Configuration=Release /v:d</buildArgs>
    <timeout>900</timeout>
  </msbuild>
</tasks>`

Finally, here is the trace log at the end of the msbuild process / restart of server.

```
Done building target "Build" in project "MYAPP.sln".
Done Building Project "C:\CCNet\WD\NET\Main\MYAPP\MYAPP.sln" (default targets).     

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s) 

Time Elapsed 00:00:05.35    

2014-08-26 20:11:41,881 [NET.App.MYAPP] [INFO] - Delete merged file 'C:\CCNet\BuildArtifacts\NET.App.MYAPP\msbuild-results-dcf002da-d0d0-4d0a-8b86-fb25adaf1ac3.xml'.
2014-08-26 20:11:46,478 [NET.App.MYAPP] [INFO] - Integration complete: Success - 8/26/2014 8:11:41 PM
2014-08-26 20:11:46,579 [NET.App.MYAPP] [INFO] - Integrator for project: NET.App.MYAPP is now stopped.
2014-08-26 20:11:57,444 [257] [INFO] - CruiseControl.NET Server 1.8.5.0 -- .NET Continuous Integration Server
2014-08-26 20:11:57,465 [257] [INFO] - Copyright © 2003 - 2014 ThoughtWorks Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
2014-08-26 20:11:57,466 [257] [INFO] - .NET Runtime Version: 2.0.50727.5477     Image Runtime Version: v2.0.50727
2014-08-26 20:11:57,467 [257] [INFO] - OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601  Service Pack 1           Server locale: English (United States)
2014-08-26 20:11:57,467 [257] [INFO] - Reason: File change delay finished
2014-08-26 20:11:57,944 [CCNet Server] [INFO] - Reading configuration file "C:\CCNet\Server\ccnet.config"
2014-08-26 20:11:58,347 [CCNet Server] [WARN] - Configuration does not have any version information - assuming the configuration is for version 1.8
2014-08-26 20:11:58,800 [CCNet Server] [INFO] - Log cache time set to 5 minutes
2014-08-26 20:11:58,990 [CCNet Server] [INFO] - Registered channel: tcp
2014-08-26 20:11:58,991 [CCNet Server] [INFO] - CruiseManager: Listening on url: tcp://32.32.29.129:21234/CruiseManager.rem
2014-08-26 20:11:58,992 [CCNet Server] [INFO] - Registered channel: tcp
2014-08-26 20:11:58,993 [CCNet Server] [INFO] - CruiseServerClient: Listening on url: tcp://32.32.29.129:21234/CruiseServerClient.rem
2014-08-26 20:11:58,994 [CCNet Server] [INFO] - Starting CruiseControl.NET Server
```

Comment: You could have a look at changing the logging level in the ccservice.exe.config; it may give a bit more detail. http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Server_Application_Config_File

Comment: I've added the trace output that I'm getting at the end of the build / restart of the server. The only part I found interesting was the 'Reason' line, but I'm not sure what that means.

Here's a link to it in the CCNet code -
https://github.com/ccnet/CruiseControl.NET/blob/master/project/service/CCService.cs

Comment: Update for today - it ran 20-30 builds of different projects this morning, and only restarted after 2 of them. I'm going to leave it running for a couple of more days and see if there is any consistency on the projects and/or change types that trigger restarts.

Comment: Although I have seen it occur 3 times in the past 5 days, the incidences of this problem have been drastically reduced. I've seen numerous .NET builds run and not trigger a restart. There has been no rhyme or reason so far on what has caused the problem (the 3 incidences were all on different projects). Only known change is I'm now running 100% as a service instead of through the console.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like ccnet is noticing a change to a .dll file within the application directory and restarting to assimilate the changes.

Ccnet is looking for changes to *any* .dll file so if your build outputs at least one to this directory it would cause a restart.

Comment: That said, i would have expected to see `One or more DLLs have changed ...` in the log.